# Determine main menu item on front page updating menu--main.html.twig

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I am trying to write a custom twig for menu--main.html.twig under Drupal 8.3.  When in the menu_links macro while on the home page, the item.in_active_trail is not TRUE.  I tried to compare the path('') to item.url but it never returns true.  I can print out both path('') and item.url and see that they output the same exact text (character for character).  Is there a special way to determine if the item.url is the front page or to string compare URL strings?

```
{{ path('<front>') == item.url ? 'true' : 'false' }} ==> 'false'
{{ path('<front>') }} ==> '/drupal8_test/'
{{ item.url }} ==> '/drupal8_test/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the path from `item.url` you would have to use the method `toString()`:

```
  {{ item.url.tostring }}
```

Instead of comparing strings a better approach might be to check for the route name of the frontpage:

```
  {% if item.url.routed and item.url.routename == '<front>' %}
    <em>Front Page</em>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  The alternative is also very clear and concise!